# Encapsulation with __getattr__ and related

Tags: python

I'm trying to encapsulate an object without changing it's default behavior, the problem is that by the time I get access to the object it's already constructed. As such, my idea is to use inheritance and use `__getattr__`, `__setattr__`, `__getitem__`, and `__setitem__` and delegate to the encapsulated object, except for fields I define myself.

```
class Request(HttpRequest):

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self._original_request = request
        super(Request, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._original_request, name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == '_original_request':
            super(Request, self).__setattr__(name, value)
        else:
            self._original_request.__setattr__(name, value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._original_request[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._original_request[key] = value
```

If I pass along the original object, everything is fine. If I don't, I get

```
host = self.META['SERVER_NAME']
KeyError: u'SERVER_NAME'
```

Am I missing something? Shouldn't my class behave exactly that the one it encapsulates?

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\www\lookwanted\djutils\views.py", line 35, in dispatch
    return super(View, self).dispatch(Request(request), *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\www\lookwanted\djutils\views.py", line 12, in __init__
    super(Request, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\http\request.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.GET, self.POST, self.COOKIES, self.META, self.FILES = {}, {}, {}, {}, {}
  File "C:\www\lookwanted\djutils\views.py", line 21, in __setattr__
    self._original_request.__setattr__(name, value)
AttributeError: can't set attribute
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 72, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 178, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 217, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 69, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 298, in get_traceback_html
    return t.render(c)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 284, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 84, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 578, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 728, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 779, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\http\request.py", line 112, in build_absolute_uri
    self.get_host(), self.path)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\http\request.py", line 62, in get_host
    host = self.META['SERVER_NAME']
KeyError: u'SERVER_NAME'
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?  Also, why are you inheriting from `HttpRequest`?

Comment: Doing so, I noticed there was another exception I wasn't noticing... I changed super(Request, self).__setattr__(name, value) to setattr(self._original_request, name, value) but now I get infinite recursion. I guess that's another question, though.

Comment: Certainly not your problem, but I don't really get the line `super(Request, self).__setattr__(name, value)` -- why don't you simply write `self._original_request = value`?

Comment: Those two lines are hardly equivalent =\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the line:

```
    super(Request, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

this will lead to the `__init__` method of the `HttpRequest` class being called on your `Request` instance which does not make sense. Therefore, just get rid of that line.

Also, I don't get it why you are subclassing in the first place. Since python has duck typing, and you are completely wrapping the inner object, why don't you go with:

```
class Request(object):
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self._original_request = request

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._original_request, name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == '_original_request':
            super(Request, self).__setattr__(name, value)
        else:
            self._original_request.__setattr__(name, value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._original_request[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._original_request[key] = value
```

Comment: +1 for spotting the erroneous sub-classing! Since `META` is an attribute of `HttpRequest`, by sub-classing it, your "interceptor" will gain its own `META` attribute, and so, `__getattr__` is _not_ triggered ... hence not accessing the `META` attribute of the original object.

Comment: I get it! Nice catch! About inheritance, would it cause harm? I was thinking about leaving it as it was, if for nothing else it documents that the two classes are related.

Comment: In fact, this is an interesting comment. Since this is python, there is no need to use subtyping to obtain substitutability - this is something that would require an interface in languages like Java. So there is some sense of inheritance here.
On the other hand, the Request object "is" not an HttpRequest object in the sense of classic Java inheritance in which constructing the subtype would entail constructing the supertype through a constructor call.
Personally, I would avoid it but I don't think there is a documented best way for doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace shows the problem: the code is trying to set attributes on `self._original_request` instead of `self.__dict__`.

Read the Python documentation for [Customizing attribute access](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__).